# Freaks out vs. scares

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, phrases, meaning-in-context

I want to know if these two sentences have the same meaning or not

> - Everyone *freaks out* at first.
> - Everybody *scares* in the start.

If they are not similar what is the best way to use *scares*.

Comment: Not the way you're using it.

Comment: So what is the best way then?

Comment: "Scare" is not generally used in an intransitive sense.

Comment: Dictionaries contain definitions of these words, list whether such verbs are transitive or not and other useful characteristics, and contain numerous examples. Consult your dictionary, not us.

Comment: It's interesting that 'John scares easily' is fine while 'John scares at first' is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sentences do not have the same meaning, as according to colloquial English, the second one doesn't make much sense.

In the example, it appears that "to scare", when conjugated as "scares", becomes a transitive verb (requires an object). At the same time, "to freak out", when conjugated as "freaks out", becomes an intransitive verb (doesn't require an object).

It follows that the second sentence seems nonsensical because "scares" is missing its object. An example of better usage of "scares" might be:

> My dog scares me.

You might find this helpful:

https://www.uvu.edu/writingcenter/docs/handouts/grammar/typesofverbs.pdf

disclaimer: native English speaker with no formal research

Comment: _Scare_ may also be used intransitively: 'He scares easily.'  As a dictionary will show. / Thanks for visiting ELU, Alice, but an answer with 'disclaimer ... no formal research' is precisely what does not make for a good answer, especially when it misses important facts. / I agree that 'scare' probably only sounds idiomatic as an intransitive verb when given appropriate 'padding' (such as 'easily').

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. I now accept that if I continue to participate on this forum, I will need to be more thorough with my answers and provide references.

Comment: It's good enough for me. Your answer is correct, it has a reference, a link, and you have said that you are a native speaker. @EdwinAshworth has been too harsh with a newcomer who produced an original answer, which did not consist of copy and paste, and whose greatest fault was being honest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'Everybody gets scared at the start.' Note that the verb in that sentence is 'gets', while 'scared' is the past participle of the verb 'to scare' and functioning as an adjective.